# Why do I receive 'message too big' on .publish() [error 1009]?

Tags: websocket, ros

I'm able to establish a firm connection over `rosbridge_server` with `roslibjs`, however, whenever I call `.publish()` the Websocket disconnects and returns

I've tried calling JSON.stringify() to shorten the message size.
I've ensure the message is of the right format.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.robotwebtools.org/EventEmitter2/current/eventemitter2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.robotwebtools.org/roslibjs/current/roslib.min.js"></script>
var ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({ 
    url : 'ws://192.168.1.122:9090'
  });
var rosbridge_obj = new ROSLIB.Topic({
    ros : ros,
    name : '/topicname',
    messageType : 'topicname/messagetype'
  });
 var message_obj = new ROSLIB.Message({
    header : {
      seq : 0,
      stamp : 8768,
      frame_id : 'Redacted',
    },
    mobility : {
      ForwardY : 0,
      TurningX : 0,
    },
    arm : {
      J1 : 0,
      J2 : 0,
      J3 : 0,
      J4 : 0,
      J51 : 0,
      J52 : 0,
    },
    mode : {
      mode : 0,
    },
  });
rosbridge_obj.publish(message_obj);
```

Expected result is that the Websocket will publish and not close however I receive the following:

```
CloseEvent
bubbles: false
code: 1009
composed: false
 currentTarget: WebSocket {url: "ws://192.168.1.122:9090/", readyState: 3, bufferedAmount: 0, onopen: ƒ, onerror: ƒ, …}
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 0
isTrusted: true
path: []
reason: "message too big"
returnValue: true
```

Comment: Try small message size and see what will be the behavior because error code says its because of size of the message size is higher that  maximim limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a hardware specific issue. The issue was completely resolved after switching to new hardware.

Comment: It might be better to flag your answer for that, questions that can no longer be reproduced are unlikely to help others.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem using [roslibpy](https://github.com/gramaziokohler/roslibpy), I was running basic examples of publisher and the connection was closed immediately after publishing the message with error:

```
WebSocket connection closed: Code=1009, Reason=message too big
```

It turns out, `rosbridge_websocket.launch` has a parameter `max_message_size` which is by default set to `None`. When I changed it to `Inf` it started working.

If you have your own launch file:

```
<include file="$(find rosbridge_server)/launch/rosbridge_websocket.launch">
    <arg name="max_message_size" value="Inf" />
</include>
```

or just (from the command line):

```
roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch max_message_size:=Inf
```

Hope this will help, it helped me.